# Argumentos función main

Tags: c, array

Para acceder al primer elemento del array de argumentos de la función main es:

```
 argv[0]:
```

o con:

```
 argv[1];
```

Comment: El numero de elemento que quieras seleccionar -1, en este caso argv[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argv[0] "representa" el nombre del ejecutable, lo cual puede ser el nombre del ejecutable con o sin path o estar vacío según el SO y la implementación, así que el primer argumento estaría en argv[1]

> 174 -  If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name;
>
> 174 - si el valor de argc es mayor que cero, la cadena apuntada desde argv[0] "representa" el nombre del programa;

---

> 175 - argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment.
>
> 175 - argv[0][0] debe ser null si el nombre del programa no está disponible desde el ambiente anfitrión. (por ej: el sistema operativo)

---

> 176 - If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program parameters.
>
> 176 - si el valor de argc es mayor a uno, las cadenas apuntadas por argv[1] hasta argv[argc-1] representan los parámetros del programa.

referencia:

http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html